# How to install mingw-w64 using pip on Windows?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, mingw-w64

I need to use the `mingw-w64` compiler toolchain for a package (pystan, if it helps). The straightforward instruction I can find to install it is by using conda, which goes:

```py
conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
```

It turns out `libpython` is a conda's mingw-w64 import library for python, hence it seems specifically designed for this type of job. However, now I want to do the installation on the stand-alone python environment, hence using `pip` instead of `conda`. The problem is I can't find a similar library to be used with `pip` (there is a module named `libpython` but it's completely different). The following doesn't work:

```py
pip install libpython m2w64-toolchain
```

I wonder if there's a similar way to install the mingw-w64 module using pip?

Comment: Unlike `conda`, `pip` is not a generic package manager; it only installs Python packages. `libpython` and `m2w64-toolchain` are not Python packages so they cannot be installed with `pip`.

Answer (score -1):

Search for mingw-get-setup.exe at Source Forge
and download the file. You can then install a minimalist mingw that will allow you to select additional library modules to ensure you have the required gcc/g++ or Cygwin environment for your installed python. Probably it will also work with the minimalist MINGW without any further tweaking.
I hope this helps you

Elifuraha - Tanzania

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).